# What are the guidelines for accepting/rejecting suggested edits?

Tags: discussion

I have recently acquired 2k reputation, and can now review suggested edits. Over the last several days I looked at an occasional pending edit, and *not a single time* could decide whether I should accept or decline it.

In several cases the suggested edits were very minor. In one case somebody edited another person's answer in quite a substantial way. All of them were probably borderline cases, but without any explicit guidelines how am I supposed to decide whether the edit should be accepted or rejected?

I thought I could learn by example and see what suggested edits get accepted and rejected by the more experienced users. For this I need to browse through the history of edits, but weird enough I cannot find it! In particular, this page https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history is empty. Am I just missing an obvious link somewhere?

Comment: After posting my question, I found this one: [Handling “suggested edits” to posts](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/handling-suggested-edits-to-posts) by @Macro which renders mine almost a duplicate. However, I am still extremely curious to find out how to browse the history of edits (if it's possible at all).

Comment: The history page is not empty when I look at it.

Comment: @gung: But do you see there the history of all reviewed edits, or only the edits you reviewed?

Comment: All edits, I was >2k when the new review system came online. It may be that it's only showing you the edits that have happened since you turned 2k+.

Comment: @gung: This cannot be true: I turned 2k+ a couple of days ago, but see nothing there. But actually I noticed a "show skipped reviews" check button there; it does not change anything for me, probably because I did not "skip" any reviews (instead, I did nothing). So it might be, that the history only shows the reviews that one accepted, rejected or skipped. If so, I should start skipping reviews I am not sure about to be able to check later how the others voted. Still, if true, I find such history behaviour a bit weird.

Comment: I don't know, but I can definitely see reviews that I neither accepted, rejected or skipped.

Comment: @gung: I found out the answer: one needs 10k rep to see the general review history. Until then one only has access to one's own review history. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Huh, I've never heard of that, but then I was 10k+ when the new review system came online. Hmm, consistent with that idea, I only see my own edits on SO, where my rep is ~3k.

Comment: @amoeba You shouldn't expect to be able to tell in every case, it's a learning process. Don't be afraid to reject edits as too minor, but if you're unsure about an edit, just skip it, someone else will get it. I still skip the odd Suggested Edit now and then and I've done over 900 of them.