# How can I figure out why my reviewer privileges were revoked and how can I get them back?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, review

This question concerns me personally, but some parts of it might also be of general interest.

During the last week or so, I had been regularly reviewing first posts and late answers. Yesterday @gung told me that I should only tell users to use the self-study tag, not do it for them (I had been doing both). I acknowledged @gung's concern. (This short conversation took place via comments on my most recent post and has since been deleted.)

However, when I next checked the review queues, I found that I no longer had access to them. The stated reason was "Too many of your reviews were rejected". I have several comments / questions about this:

- After acknowledging @gung's point (which I think is very valid), I did not review any more posts. Thus it felt like I was never even given a chance to "improve my ways".
- Is there a way I can see which of my reviews were rejected and why? (I understand from [this post](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2517/182174), [this post](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2147/182174) and [the overview of moderator tools](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) that some of this information is only available to user with 10k in reputation or more.)
- Do people get banned from the review queues after hitting some threshold or do moderators manually ban them?
- Is there a specific cool-off period after which banned users can access the review queues again or will that be at the discretion of moderators?

**Let me add that it is not my intention to criticize the work of our tireless moderators.** This site has been very helpful to me on occasion and I try to give back a bit through writing a few answers when I can and to contribute my two cents to the moderation of the site. I am happy to respond to whatever feedback I get and also to stay away from the review queues if I'm doing more harm than good.

Comment: You don't give the impression you're being critical - indeed you're asking politely; it's perfectly reasonable to ask questions about what happened.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your efforts to try to improve the site are appreciated!

As I understand it, if enough reviews / suggested edits are rejected you'll automatically generate a (temporary) ban without any intervention by a moderator.

This should lift in a few days.

[If it's still there on Monday, please notify a moderator; we should be able to reverse it.]

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful!

Comment: I realize I didn't quite cover all of your questions in my answer, but I figured it would be worth posting a partial answer so you didn't worry overly much about an automatic and temporary issue.

Comment: You actually do cover most of my questions. I guess the one lingering question - from a community-building perspective - is whether it wouldn't make sense to give users more information on their accepted vs rejected reviews (though it might be the case that it's too much of a fringe issue to be worth too much thinking about it).

Comment: This may be a good idea; if you have a concrete proposal (for which something similar hasn't already been floated), it might be worth considering a post to the network meta (meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I cleared the ban @Candamir, we have the ability to override the period before it's ended. I appreciate your efforts to improve the site.

Comment: @gung thank you!

Comment: @Glen_b That's a good idea, I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: @Glen_b I spent some time on meta.stackexchange.com and saw some posts ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228927/374164) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303584/374164)) that suggest to me that the feature of telling users for how long they've been banned from reviews is available at least on SO. Can that be the case? Or maybe the issue is that what the user sees depends on whether he was banned automatically or banned manually by a moderator? I tried to look everywhere when I was banned and I don't think I saw *any* message explaining the nature or the duration of the ban.

Comment: @Glen_b feel free to use me as a guinea pig for a manual ban if needed :)

Comment: If you get temporarily banned by a moderator you're definitely notified of the length (I'm not going to do it to show you though, since mention of it stays on your account). I expect that you should see even the duration of a temporary ban on your user page but maybe that's not the case; if it happens on stackoverflow it will already be in place here as well. [A moderator can look for you if it's an issue.]